# how can I make my numerous button activated functions into one function that handles all numbers?

Tags: python

Okay, so I have my code to replace numbers or switch them for a "*" symbol, yet it's spread out over ten functions for each individual number because they are button activated, and I was curious if it's possible to take ten buttons that handle ten different numbers and put it into one button or something. Here is my entire code:

```
import Tkinter
import re
from math import sqrt, modf
from numpy import arange
from random import randint
from Tkconstants import END
import sys


def remove_one():
    h = randint(1,2)  # create 1/2 and 1/2 effect, 50% chance
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace('1', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace('1', "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)


def remove_two():
    h = randint(1,2)  # create 1/2 and 1/2 effect, 50% chance
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace('2', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace('2', "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)


def remove_three():
    h = randint(1,2)  # create 1/2 and 1/2 effect, 50% chance
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace('3', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace('3', "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)


def remove_four():
    h = randint(1,2)  # create 1/2 and 1/2 effect, 50% chance
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace('4', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace('4', "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)


def remove_five():
    h = randint(1,2)  # create 1/2 and 1/2 effect, 50% chance
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace('5', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace('5', "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)


def remove_six():
    h = randint(1,2)  # create 1/2 and 1/2 effect, 50% chance
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace('6', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace('6', "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)


def remove_seven():
    h = randint(1,2)  # create 1/2 and 1/2 effect, 50% chance
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace('7', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace('7', "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)


def remove_eight():
    h = randint(1,2)  # create 1/2 and 1/2 effect, 50% chance
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace('8', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace('8', "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)


def remove_nine():
    h = randint(1,2)  # create 1/2 and 1/2 effect, 50% chance
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace('9', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace('9', "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)


def remove_zero():
    h = randint(1,2)  # create 1/2 and 1/2 effect, 50% chance
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace('0', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace('0', "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)


def clear_entry():  # clear entry line with blank string
    E1.delete(0, END)
    E1.insert(0, '')


def fun_with_reverse():
    text = str(E1.get())
    if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', text):  # Make sure it's numeric only
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text="Input numbers only!").grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        master.title("Wrong input")
        master.mainloop()
    else:
        i = len(text) - 1
        result = ""
        while i > -1:
            result = result + text[i]
            i -= 1
        text = E1.get().replace('0', "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, result)


def prime_number():
    if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', str(E1.get())):  # Make sure it's numeric only
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text="Input numbers only!").grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        master.title("Wrong input")
        master.mainloop()
        sys.exit(0)
    x = float(E1.get())
    if x < 2:  # number can't be prime if it's less than 2
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text="Don't go below 2, it isn't' going to work!").grid(ipadx=5,
                                                                                                            ipady=5)
        master.title("Prime Failure")
        master.mainloop()
    else:
        n = 2
        while n < x:
            if x % n == 0:  # can't be prime if it can be divided by anything besides one or itself
                master = Tkinter.Tk()
                w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text="The number is not prime!").grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
                master.title("Prime Failure")
                master.mainloop()
                break
            n += 1
        else:
            master = Tkinter.Tk()
            w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text="The number is prime!").grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
            master.title("Prime Success")
            master.mainloop()


def radical():
    # Define variables needed
    if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', str(E1.get())):  # Make sure it's numeric only
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text="Input numbers only!").grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        master.title("Wrong input")
        master.mainloop()
        sys.exit(0)
    a = float(E1.get())
    b = (a + 1)
    c = sqrt(b)
    e = sqrt(a)
    f = (unichr(0x221A))
    fractional, integral = modf(c)
    for integral in arange(integral, 0, -1):  # loop to get fractional1 == 0
        fractional1, integral1 = modf(a / (integral ** 2))
        print(fractional1)
        if fractional1 != 0:
            integral -= 1
            continue
        else:
            break
    '''while integral == integral:
        fractional1, integral1 = modf(a / (integral**2))
        print(fractional1)
        if fractional1 != 0:
            integral -= 1
            continue
        else: break'''
    d = (a / (integral ** 2))
    if integral.is_integer():
        integral = int(integral)
    if d.is_integer():
        d = int(d)
    if e.is_integer():
        e = int(e)
    # set conditions for output
    if d == 1:
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text=(integral)).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        master.title("Square Root")
        master.mainloop()
    elif integral == 1:
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text=(f, d, "or", e)).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        master.title("Simplified Radical")
        master.mainloop()
    else:
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text=(integral, f, d, "or", e)).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        master.title("Simplified Radical")
        master.mainloop()


def factorial():
    if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', str(E1.get())):
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text="Input numbers only!").grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        master.title("Wrong input")
        master.mainloop()
    else:
        x = float(E1.get())
    if x > 170:  # anything 170+ results in 'inf', so create barrier
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text="You can't go above 170!")
        w.pack()
        master.mainloop()
        sys.exit(0)
    fact = 1
    for i in arange(1, x + 1):  # use arange to allow for float values, although 4! == 24 and 4.1! == 120 (5! ==120)
        fact *= i
    if fact.is_integer():
        fact = int(fact)
    master = Tkinter.Tk()
    w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5, text=fact)
    w.config(font=('times', 19, 'italic'))
    w.pack()
    master.mainloop()
    return fact


def program_quit():
    Tkinter.sys.exit(0)  # Quit python
    sys.exit(0)


# define main GUI for program
root = Tkinter.Tk()
E1 = Tkinter.Entry(root)
assert isinstance(E1, object)
E1.grid(columnspan=2, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Determine Factorial', command=factorial).grid(row=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B2 = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Exit', command=program_quit).grid(row=9, columnspan=2, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B3 = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Simplify Radical', command=radical).grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B4 = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Determine Prime', command=prime_number).grid(row=2, ipadx=5, ipady=5,
                                                                             sticky='W''E')
B5 = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Reverse the numbers', command=fun_with_reverse).grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5,
                                                                                     sticky='W''E')
B6 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Remove/* 1's", command=remove_one).grid(row=3, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B7 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Remove/* 2's", command=remove_two).grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B8 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Remove/* 3's", command=remove_three).grid(row=4, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B9 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Remove/* 4's", command=remove_four).grid(row=4, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B10 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Remove/* 5's", command=remove_five).grid(row=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B11 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Remove/* 6's", command=remove_six).grid(row=5, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B12 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Remove/* 7's", command=remove_seven).grid(row=6, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B13 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Remove/* 8's", command=remove_eight).grid(row=6, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B14 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Remove/* 9's", command=remove_nine).grid(row=7,ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B15 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Remove/* 0's", command=remove_zero).grid(row=7, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
B16 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Clear Entry", command=clear_entry).grid(row=8, columnspan=2, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
root.mainloop()
```

so, like, if I enter 0123456789, I want a button that'll take out 4 or change it to *, and then later I wanna change 2 or 7 or something, but I don't want a window full of buttons or a code full of functions that do the same thing with different number

Comment: Too little details in your question. How do you connect your functions to the buttons, what framework are you using for the "buttons"? Probably some lambda expression is going to be an answer here.

Comment: posted the entire code for ya

Comment: You have your answer already below.

Comment: that doesn't exactly answer my question, I thought my question was a bit absurd, but then I thought, there's bound to be some genius out there who can figure out how to make a button that chooses the number you want and only affects that specific number without having a screen full of buttons and without typing in the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
def remove_number(num):
    h = randint(1,2)
    if h == 1:
        text = E1.get().replace(num, "")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
    else:
        text = E1.get().replace(num, "*")
        E1.delete(0, END)
        E1.insert(0, text)
```

And here's the magic:

```
buttons = []
for character in '0123456789':
    button = Tkinter.Button(root, text="button"+character,
                 command=lambda character=character: remove_num(character)))
    buttons.append(button)
```

Actually, I'd suggest having an `Entry` or `OptionMenu` where the user can choose the character, and then a single `Button` whose command grabs the chosen value.

Comment: Well, the thing about this code is it always creates button9, and it only chooses 9, I need it to choose whatever the user wants, but with the simplicity of a button click, no extra GUI's, and all those buttons make the GUI unappealing to use.

Comment: Are you adding each button to the GUI with your preferred geometry manager, or just doing `button.grid()` at the end? Remember that the individual buttons are all in the `list` named `buttons`.

Comment: And I certainly hope that you don't expect the program to know which of ten options the user has in mind with only a single button and no other GUI elements.

Comment: No, I'm kinda lost at why I asked actually.